# Python script can connect to local SQL Server successfully but batch file running this same Python script cannot access SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, automation, pyodbc

I have a Python script that successfully connects to my local SQL Server, which is great. But I would like to run this script periodically by running a batch file containing instructions to run this Python script.

When the batch file is ran, the script runs until it hits the SQL Server connection part (shown here with the server and db name changed):

```
databaseConnection = pyodbc.connect(
    'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
    'Server=<servername>;'
    'Database=<databasename>;'
    'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    'Integrated Security=SSPI;'
    )
```

The issue I get from running the batch file (in cmd) is this:

```
databaseConnection = pyodbc.connect(
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SQL Server Network Interfaces: The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.\r\n [x89C50107].  (-1983577849) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (-1983577849)')
```

Does anyone know why my script would connect to my local SQL Server when running it manually but not connect when trying to connect it after being executed by a batch script?

Comment: So what's executing the batch file? LocalDB depends on the correct user profile being loaded. See also: [SQL Server Express LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb) and [LOCALDB_ERROR_CANNOT_GET_USER_PROFILE_FOLDER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/express-localdb-error-messages/localdb-error-cannot-get-user-profile-folder).

Comment: I am executing the batch file manually. But I plan on having it run through an automated task in Windows. 
I had this batch file executing on my old computer successfully, but now I am executing on my new computer and it won't work anymore.